# How do I set auth() manually in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I am not using any of the laravel authentication. I am authenticating user manually. I have the user details beforehand and I want to set the user to `auth()->user()` manually. How do I do it?

Comment: `Auth::login($user);`
You can read the documentation here [Laravel - Other authentifcation methods](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to login a user, you can achieve this using Auth::login($user).

Example:

```
Auth::login($user);

// Login and "remember" the given user...
Auth::login($user, true);
```

See laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#other-authentication-methods